# org.apache.jasper.JasperException

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, jakarta-ee

When i open first time my application its show error like

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:460)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:373)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:183)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:125)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:107)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:78)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:383)
```

But i refreshed again then it will open fine without error.

What is the problem and how to fix this?

Please can any one help me...

Comment: Need more information. Put the entire JSP in a `try-catch` block, catch `Throwable`, print stacktrace of the `Throwable` and post back the output.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like your application requires some initialization of code which takes time. now while you open the page it is initializing things in background and you see error due to uninitialized or partial initialized values.

you can add some auto initializers or wait for some time to get it loaded completely.

Comment: Where exactly i need to change for auto initializers?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extract of relevance of the `JspServletWrapper#handleJspException()` source.

```
456         // If the line number is less than one we couldn't find out
457         // where in the JSP things went wrong
458         int jspLineNumber = detail.getJspBeginLineNumber();
459         if (jspLineNumber < 1) {
460             throw new JasperException(ex);
461         }
```

Apparently the JSP was empty on first access. What frameworks are you using? I haven't seen a framework before which autogenerates JSP files on startup or something like that. It might need some configuration finetuning.

Comment: Actually previously we were using tomcat 5 and working fine, but now we upgrade to tomcat 5.5, so any other things has to be change?

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem because of web.xml misconfiguration.

I tried to add *.jar to be served by JspServlet.

You certainly did an error in Servlet mapping in your web.xml.